# Upload changed files only to az blob container folder

Tags: azure-devops, azure-blob-storage

Using az devops pipeline I am deleting all files in container then upload all files instead I want to upload only last changed files using az storage blob cmdlet (like incremental backup) or any other cmdlet except azcopy,can anyone guide me to do so

Comment: why cant you use `azcopy sync`?

Comment: You can use the powershell cmdlet for the same please do refer this : https://cloud.netapp.com/blog/azure-cvo-blg-how-to-upload-files-to-azure-blob-storage

Comment: Are the answers helpful to you? Please check the answer, if it is correct, please check it as a correct one. And if you have any question,we are willing to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to use az storage blob cmdlet to upload files to Azure Storage account blob, I suggest that you can use the [az storage blob sync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-blob-sync).

For example:

```
az storage blob sync -c mycontainer -s "path/to/file" -d NewBlob
```

In Azure DevOps Pipeline, you can use [Azure CLI task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-cli?view=azure-devops) to run the command.

Comment: The command not sync folder on container, i.e on container/folder I want to sync files from $(build.sourcedir)\folder, this 'folder' need to sync with all inside content

Comment: You can Sync a directory to a container, such as `az storage blob sync -c mycontainer --account-name mystorageccount --account-key 00000000 -s "path/to/directory"`, Please have a try.